# Music bot can join but cant play a file

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Im coding an discord bot and i want to include an music player, for now im trying to play an file in the same folder

The function is being called from my main file.
I've already tried multiple stuff, but none did work,
the player const is later gonna be used to pause resume and so on

(ignore the link variable for now, its gonna be used for carrying an youtube link later)

```
module.exports = {
streamyt: function (message, link) {
    if (message.member.voiceChannel ) {
        const jchannel = message.member.voiceChannel
        jchannel.join()
        const player = jchannel.play('./Pascal.mp3')
    }
    else {
        message.reply('I cant do that,you need to be in an vc first')
    }
}
```

expected: 
The bot should join and start playing my Pascal.mp3 file

actual:
the bot connects to the vc and then crashes

```
const player = jchannel.play('./Pascal.mp3')
                        ^
TypeError: jchannel.play is not a function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently .play() is not the method of jchannel object.

```
module.exports = {
streamyt: function (message, link) {
    if (message.member.voiceChannel ) {
        const jchannel = message.member.voiceChannel
        jchannel.join().then(function (connection) {
            connection.playFile('./Pascal.mp3') 
    }
    else {
        message.reply('I cant do that,you need to be in an vc first')
    }
}
```

Comment: according to the [doc](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/master/docs/topics/voice.md): "The most basic example of playing audio over a connection would be playing a local file:
`const dispatcher = connection.play('/home/discord/audio.mp3');`
The dispatcher in this case is a StreamDispatcher - here you can control the volume and playback of the stream:...", so it according to them it should  work like that

Comment: there is a difference between `connection.play()` and `jchannel.play()`. In the code given in this answer, what is done is : try to join the voice channel, get a *VoiceConnection* object, and then use the `play` method on this connection. This is a big difference with what your code is doing, because you don't use the *VoiceConnection* returned by the `join()` method.

Comment: Got it working thanks to that comment and the new Docs (i was using the old ones[silly me]) play doesnt work anymore now its .playFile(file)